# Convert Lambda synchronise to async event issue

Tags: aws-lambda, event-handling, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework, aws-sdk-js

I am  trying to make basic todo app by using Serverless framework. My synchronous lambda function works fine and store my task and taskdetails in the dynamodb table. I decided to convert my synchronous lambda function into async function. And I am testing api by using Postman. But now I have event trigger problem, It does not store my `taskDetails`, it just store my task only. In my post man I can see event trigger and here is the [post-method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFOAd.png) and this is what I [get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss6bP.png). I don’t get what I am doing wrong in here. Ps. I am new to Lambda.

**This is synchronous lambda function**

```js
'use strict'
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const uuid = require('uuid');
const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
module.exports.createTodo = (event, context, callback) => {
  const datetime = new Date().toISOString();
  const data = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const params = {
    TableName: 'todos',
    Item: {
      id: uuid.v1(),
      task: data.task,
      taskDetails: data.taskDetails,
      done: false,
      createdAt: datetime,
      updatedAt: datetime
    }
  };
  dynamoDb.put(params, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      callback(new Error(error));
      return;
    }
const response = {
      statusCode: 201,
      body: JSON.stringify(data.Item)
    };

    callback(null, response);
  });
}
```

This is my async and put in try catch, where I got error.

```js
'use strict'
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const uuid = require('uuid');

const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

module.exports.createTodo = async event => {
  const datetime = new Date().toISOString();
  const data = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const params = {
    TableName: 'todos',
    Item: {
      id: uuid.v1(),
      task: data.task,
      taskdetails: data.taskdetails,
      done: false,
      createdAt: datetime,
      updatedAt: datetime
    }
  };

  try {
    let response = await dynamoDb.put(params).promise();
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your synchronous code you are using `taskDetails` where as in async implementation it is `taskdetails`.

I am assuming in your get method you are reading data from `taskDetails`, so your get api is not returning `taskDetails` in response.

Go to dynamodb console and check for your id you will be able to see data in `taskdetails` attribute.